# How to format a JDBC PreparedStatment with a $index parameter for Postgres

Tags: java, postgresql, jdbc

I am working with a postgres database and I'm using JDBC. Most things are working fine, but I'm getting the following error with this piece of code and it seems to be that I'm not properly using `setString`/`setDate` with a `$` style parameterized query. Without further ado, here is the code

(The variables not initialized here were initialized correctly ahead of this method call).

```java
String query = "INSERT INTO \"tracks\" (\"artist\", \"album\", \"name\", \"listened_at\", \"created_at\", \"updated_at\", \"url\", \"image_url\") VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4, $5, $6, $7, $8) RETURNING \"id\"";
PreparedStatement statement = connection.prepareStatement(query);
java.sql.Date current = new java.sql.Date((new Date()).getTime());
java.sql.Date sqlListenedAt = new java.sql.Date(listenedAt.getTime());
statement.setString(1, artist);
statement.setString(2, album);
statement.setString(3, name);
statement.setDate(4, sqlListenedAt);
statement.setDate(5, current);
statement.setDate(6, current);
statement.setString(7, url);
statement.setString(8, imageUrl);
```

and the error that I'm getting is as follows

```
org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: The column index is out of range: 1, number of columns: 0.
```

Is there a way to properly use a `INSERT INTO "table" ("column_a", "column_b") VALUES ($1, $2)` style statement with JDBC?

Comment: Doesn't `VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)` work? I think you have to define a parameter for a query with the interrogation mark.

Comment: I prefer `INSERT INTO "table" ("column_a", "column_b") VALUES (:column_a, :column_b)` form with `statement.setXXX("column_a", value);`

Comment: Unrelated, but: all those escaped double quotes are useless. You can make your String much easier to read if you remove them.

Comment: deHaar is right: plain JDBC uses `?` as the placeholder. There is no alternative. If you want something different, you would need to use e.g. Spring JDBC Template which allows for named parameters

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
String query = "INSERT INTO tracks (artist, album, name, listened_at, created_at, updated_at, url, image_url) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?) RETURNING id";
```

I think the rest of your code is probably okay. Two basic comments:

-You only need to quote your table / column names when they are otherwise reserved words in SQL. The way you wrote it is really hard to read.

-JDBC uses ? for placeholders. I've never seen $1 etc. Maybe that works, but I don't think so.